# Power app display all rows of a column in textbox

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

new to Powerapp. I have a excel data source with 2 columns (Customer and Note). I want to display all the notes (regardless of customers) in a textbox.  What is the simplest way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Concat function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) to merge all the rows for a certain column, like in the example below:

```
Concat(<ExcelTableName>, Note, ", ")
```